# Why doesn't it put the element on a string of a new list?

Tags: java, string, list

I have a list of list of strings, and I want to get some strings from it to store them in a new list of list of strings. Here's the code:

```
    List<List<String>> colectieTotala = new ArrayList<>();
    List<List<String>> dePusInRaport = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> listaPentruTest = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;

    dePusInRaport.add(listaPentruTest);

for (int y = 0; y < colectieTotala.size(); y++) 
    {
        String categorie;
        String categorieCurenta = "";
        char spatiu = ' ';
        int h = 0;
        List<String> toateCategoriileCurente = new ArrayList<>();
        colectieTotala.get(y).get(0);
        categorie = colectieTotala.get(y).get(1);
        colectieTotala.get(y).get(4);

        if (categorie.contains(" "))
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < categorie.length(); k++)
            {
                for (int p = 0; p < dePusInRaport.size(); p++)
                {
                if ((categorie.charAt(k)) == spatiu)
                {
                    categorieCurenta = categorie.substring(h, k);
                    h = k+1;
                    dePusInRaport.get(p).add(categorieCurenta); 
                }

                if (k == categorie.lastIndexOf(spatiu))
                {
                    categorieCurenta = categorie.substring(k+1, categorie.length());
                    dePusInRaport.get(p).add(categorieCurenta);

                }


            }
            }

        }

    }
    System.out.println("dePusInRaport -> " + dePusInRaport);
```

The problem is that this code adds the strings from colectieTotala only on the first list of strings from from dePusInRaport, and what I want is getting the strings from colectieTotala and store them, each on a new List of Strings, of dePusInRaport. If you need further information, please ask for it. I'm not that good at explaining.

**So, what System.out.println("dePusInRaport -> " + dePusInRaport); prints in the end is this:**

> [[Drama, Mystery, Crime, Drama, Mystery, SF, Drama, SF, Psihologic]]

**but I want something like this:**

> [[Drama] [Mystery] [Crime] [Drama] [Mystery] [SF] [Drama] [SF] [Psihologic]]

I think there's a bad for in there, either I just forgot to add one...

Comment: Without going deep into your code, I feel you can refactor with [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and [List.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel, but still if you want to understand your code before cleaning everything and doing as Neeraj suggest, add some sysout before adding anything to your final list. You will understand your mistake.

Comment: I'm kinda messy when I code, I know, but this is just a BETA version, if I can say so... I tried what Neeraj said, but now it comes up with another error. I'll figure it out as soon as I come home. Thanks all of you !

Answer (score 0):

Not able to explain pefectly as unable to understand your `native language` ,
but what you want to achieve can be done this way .

Suppose you have

```
List<List<String>> mainList=new ArrayList<List<String>>();// in this you add

List<String> myList=Arrays.asList("ABC","PQR","XYZ");// Input List
    for(String s:myList)
    {  
          mainList.add(Arrays.asList(s));
    }
System.out.println(mainList);
```

Output

```
[[ABC], [PQR], [XYZ]]
```

Click here for **[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/QLhrX7)**

If you want to remove comma `,` then I suggest you to `override toString` method and return in whichever style you want .